# Why is Thymeleaf ignoring this ternary?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

```
Here is the line                                    

th:attr="${row.link!=null} ? onclick=|rowClicked('${row.link.url()}', '${T(java.util.Arrays).toString(row.link.params())}','${row.componentId}')|" >
```

Here is the error. I check if if row.link is null yet it sill tries to evaluate the expression. When the row.link is not null it correctly sets the onclick attribute. I have also tried appending `:` at the end and `: myattr=2` as well just to see if it needs something, those aren't event parse-able.

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "row.link.url()" (template: "fragments/table.html" - line 108, col 11)
...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method url() on null context object
```

Comment: what should it do if `row.link` is null?  nothing?

Comment: Can you also post the full tag?  Might be a better way

Comment: if row.link exists have thymeleaf add the onclick attribute which calls a javascript function called rowClicked(url, params, componentId). If row.link is null to not add the onclick attribute. I have been able to do if with th:if th:unless but that is not going to be usable going forward since there will be parent elements with similar conditions and will require tons of redundant copy paste and will double the document size with each one